Transfer of torque from the reaction wheel to the satellite body in SolidWorks
I am modeling the impact of the moment of a reaction wheel mounted on the z-axis on the body of a satellite in Solidworks.
The problem is that the moment from the reaction wheel is not transmitted to the satellite body, the wheel rotates at 3000 rpm, but the position of the satellite does not change in any way.

This is due to either the wrong type of mates (I chose concentricity and coincidence) or additional force effects.
Please tell me how to correctly create the transmission of the moment impact on the satellite body in SW.
EDIT: I managed to generate this motion via Force/Torque PropertyManager. But it's still not the same. I plan to transfer the model to Simmechanics and set control signals, so the reaction should be defined via mechanical couplings. I don't know if it will work via forces set via Force/Torque Manager.


If the wheel is at constant speed there is no torque, other than friction.

@GregLocock yes, that's why I set the acceleration, but the moment is still not transferred to the satellite's body

Uh, you said the wheel was turning at 3000 rpm. That isn't accelerating. FWIW I can't help you with software side of things because i don't know anything about Mickey Mouse dynamics programs. My guess is that you have selected an (impossible, but often used) single ended force on the wheel, rather than a force/reaction pair. That is, you have to accelerate the wheel via a torque between the wheel and the other body.

@GregLocock I misspoke. Acceleration after integrating give velocity, that's what I meant. It's not the point. You're right, I do set the motor to the wheel (motion on 1-st gif). Then I tried adding a reaction using the Force/Task Manager (I wrote about it, motion on 2-nd gif). Problem with this method is that all reactions must be determined by existing mechanical couplings, and not by points of force application. 1-st is transferred to SimMechanics. 2-nd is not (afaik). Here is an example of another configuration in which moment effects are remarkably reproduced: https://postimg.cc/rDmTKY5Q

@GregLocock maybe it should be like this, and I don't quite understand something correctly, but adding reactions manually in a case where they should be determined automatically is perceived as an additional "crutch". Moreover, only the force is specified, but the required acceleration, speed or position cannot be specified in this way.

@GregLocock just checked: the reactive moment set via Force/Torque Manager is not transferred to SimMechanics. The moment from the wheel to the satellite body is not transferred.
